# Are these queries correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, subquery

I have following tables:

**Mall:**

```
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| MallID    | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name      | varchar(45)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Store:**

```
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| StoreID    | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| MallID     | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Name       | varchar(45)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Revenue    | int(10)              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Customer:**

```
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| CustomerID | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| StoreID    | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Name       | varchar(45)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Age        | smallint(3)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`Store.MallID` is foreign key of `Mall.MallID` and `Customer.StoreID` is foreign key of `Store.StoreID`

1 - I want to select all Malls which have total store revenue greater than 100000.

`select * from Mall where 100000 < ( select sum(Revenue) from Store where Mall.MallID = Store.MallID);`

2 - I want to select name of Malls which doesn't have any customers.

`select Name from Mall where 0 = ( select count(*) from Customer, Store where Mall.MallID = Store.MallID and Store.StoreID = Customer.StoreID);`

**Are these queries correct?**

Comment: have you checked for that..???

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ is your friend, create the tables there and check if your queries are good

Comment: I have checked this. It seems to work fine, but I am not sure if it's proper way to get such results.

Comment: I think it's correct, but I suggest you to use aliases for your tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries do what you expect.  I would write the second using ANSI standard `join` syntax and encourage you to use abbreviations as table aliases:

```
select Name
from Mall m
where 0 = (select count(*)
           from Customer c join
                Store s 
                on Mall.MallID = Store.MallID 
           where Store.StoreID = Customer.StoreID
          );
```

An alternative formulation is to do it all as a single join and aggregation:

```
select m.Name
from Mall m left outer join
     Store s
     on s.MallID = m.MallID left outer join
     Customer c
     on s.StoredId = c.StoreId
group by m.Name
having count(c.CustomerId) = 0;
```

In MySQL I would discourage you from doing the aggregation in a subquery and then joining it in.  Although a very good SQL solution, MySQL actually creates the derived table for such subqueries, which can sometimes have a negative impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

They're correct, but there are better (IMHO) ways to write them:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Mall m
JOIN (SELECT MallID, SUM(Revenue) totalRev
      FROM Store
      GROUP BY MallID
      HAVING totalRev > 100000) s
ON s.MallID = m.MallID

SELECT m.Name
FROM Mall m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT s.MallID
           FROM Customer c
           JOIN Store s
           ON c.StoreID = s.StoreID) s
ON m.MallID = s.MallID
WHERE s.MallID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

They're correct, I've checked them for you here :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a496/12

You can either use some of the suggested sql commands, or keep yours (So many ways to write a query !)

1.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Mall 
where MallID in (
      SELECT MallID
      FROM Store
      GROUP BY MallID
      HAVING SUM(Revenue) > 100000)
```

2.

```
SELECT Name
FROM Mall
WHERE (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM Customer, Store 
       WHERE Mall.MallID = Store.MallID and Store.StoreID = Customer.StoreID
      )=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use outer join in query 2 as there could be a empty mall with no store and hence no customer.

```
select Name from Mall where 0 = ( select count(*) from Customer, Store where Mall.MallID(+) = Store.MallID and Store.StoreID = Customer.StoreID);
```

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: . . `count(*)` returns `0` when there are no matches.